# How to append to an Integer

Tags: java, append, concatenation

On a project I've been working on, I came across a problem, where I need to append a single digit to an `Integer`. The problem is you can't append to an `Integer`, with a simple solution like: `Integer.append(someArrayOfNumbers)`or`someDigit.append(aNumber).` And there's not really any *good* information on it. So I was wanting to know some algorithms and "*such*".

Comment: could put some example about problem statement. ??

Comment: @downvoter Could you explain please?

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to multiply the int by 10 and add the digit, or if the int is negative, minus the digit:

```
youtInt * 10 + (yourInt < 0 ? -yourDigit : yourDigit)
```

If you want to append any number of digits, multiply the int by `pow(10, log10(yourDigits) + 1)`.

Another solution is to convert the int to a string and add the digit at the end of the string, and convert it back to an int:

```
Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(yourInt) + Integer.toString(yourDigit))
```

Comment: In your first example, what if you need to append more than one digit, to the first one? The last example will work *every* time, but what if your not allowed to use `String`'s or a `Parser`?

Comment: @StarCoder Can't you do that multiple times? If you have multiple digits, like `55`, you can multiply the int by `pow(10, floor(log10(yourDigits)) + 1)`

Comment: Yes, but what if you want something "*quick*", and "*clean*"? Without using `String`'s.

Comment: @StarCoder Is a mathematical approach not clean? Well, you can use `StringBuilder`, which should be faster than concatenating strings in a loop.

Comment: @StarCoder What's dirty about strings? If you're trying to concatenate values, strings are the natural solution. Perhaps not the most efficient, but certainly clean.

Comment: @shmosel I didn't say `String`'s were dirty, and they are effiecent. But sometimes you are required, not, to use `String`'s.

Comment: @StarCoder I've never bumped into such a requirement in the real world.

Comment: @Sweeper It can be a little harder to read with a few ternary operators next to each other.

Comment: @shmosel More than likely not, but for a job or homework assignment, you maybe under these circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my ***base*** solution(well *part* mine, I got some info from this answer but I had to tinker, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12239029/7777)), without using a `String`. I say *base* because this algorithm doesn't work properly, if one of the array members, is more than one digit.

```
public int append(int[] arrayOfIntegers) {

    int total;
    int length = arrayOfIntegers.length; // for quick reference

    total = (int) (arrayOfIntegers[0] * Math.pow(10, length - 1)); // first item times 10 to the power of length minus 1
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        total += arrayOfIntegers[i] * Math.pow(10, length - i - 1);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Now to append to an integer:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
System.out.println("The array appended: " + append(array));
```

Output:

`The array appended: 1234567`

Comment: How about `Integer.parseInt(IntStream.of(arrayOfIntegers).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()))`

Comment: @shmosel That works, but if you how to make your own, *appender*, then this should work.

Comment: What is an *appender* and how is it different from an appender?

Comment: A thing that add's to the `Object`, that you wanting to *add* to.

Comment: Integers are immutable. I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, a new instantiated value.

Answer (score 1):

if you are appending **only one digit** to the right side or LSB then you can append by multiplying by ten and adding the new number...

```
public int append(int originalValue, int numberToAppend ) {

     return originalValue*10+ numberToAppend;
}
```

for more digits you can do using a string concatenation first

```
public int append(Integer originalValue, Integer numberToAppend ) {
     String temp =  originalValue.toString()+ numberToAppend.toString();
     return Integer.parseInt(temp);
}
```

Comment: What if you need to append more than two values?

Comment: @StarCoder I have edited my answer to show how you append multiple digits.

Comment: @Sweeper Values, not digits.

Comment: @shmosel I might have misunderstood, what does OP mean by "values"?

Comment: @Sweeper An array of ints. See OP's own answer.